# why does databinding not like a custom name for the android namespace

Tags: android, android-databinding

I noticed that when I use databinding with a layout I get a compile error if I change the android namespace name.

This block

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="object"
            type="<PATH_TO_DATA_CLASS>"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</layout>
```

compiles. This block

```
<layout
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="object"
            type="<PATH_TO_DATA_CLASS>"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</layout>
```

breaks the build with an error

```
error: unbound prefix. (at the line <LinearLayout)
```

Other layouts that don't use databinding compile with the shorter name.
Does anybody know why and how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know why

A bug, presumably. I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77607056), as data binding should be able to handle this.

> how to get around this?

Switch back to `android:`, I guess. I don't know of a way to get data binding to pay attention to the alternative namespace prefix.